# Is it possible to find and replace from list in regex?

Tags: regex

I need to replace multiple different terms in square brackets from file names using regex in File Renamer. I can do them individually but it's very time consuming, is there a way to search and replace from a list?

For example, I need to remove all the extension names in square brackets from file names like these:

```
filename[txt].txt    
File_Name(Blah)[pdf].pdf
Eman Elif - [abcdef 00] - whaterver [doc].doc
```

Thanks.

Edit: Apologies, I'm new here and dont know my way around. My example should have been more varied, not all are in the format: [ext].ext  . I was more looking for a way to match terms from a list and replace with nothing (so the term is removed) Something like:

> FIND: [pdf], [txt], [doc], [V3.0],
>
> REPLACE:

but of course that doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: "_Is it possible to find and replace from list in regex?_" Yes, it is. The word "impossible" itself says "I'm possible"!

Comment: This can likely be done simply with some clever back-references..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following regex:

```
\s?\[(txt|pdf|doc|V3\.0)\]\s?
```

and keep the replace string empty. You can add as many strings as you want inside the `()` parenthesis, separating each string with a `|` pipe character. Remember to escape special characters like `.` with `\`.

e.g: `V3\.0`

[Example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sM4xU1/3).

Comment: Great! This is an appropriate approach. By the way, this question's a trifle.

Comment: This works perfect for the above examples, thank you, but they were just an example of the type of thing I need to remove, not all are in the format: [ext].ext . I was more looking for a way to match any term from a list and replace it with nothing.

Comment: @Zarnia: I updated my answer (and example on the link) based on your updated question.

Comment: @Zarnia Glad to help. Make sure you mark the answer correct so that anyone having similar problems who sees this question can use it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group and backreference to match these:

```
s/\[([^]]*)\]\.\1$/.$1/
```

This matches a word inside square brackets followed by a dot and that word, and replaces it all with dot followed by the word.

Comment: I recommend changing `[^]]*` to `[^]]+`.